Understanding さしずめ
From Dungeon Meshi episode 16, マルシル responds to an explanation by ライオス of a dungeon creature that breaks down leftover remains of monsters and live and repair the dungeon walls after damage has been done. マルシル likens this creature's behavior as similar in process to healing in living creatures:

ライオス: 彼らが邪魔だと判断した物はすべて分解されてしまうからな。
竜の死骸や爆発の残骸を食べにきたんだろう。
迷宮内が傷つくと現れて
分泌液で延焼や倒壊を防ぐんだ。
そして周囲に散らかったゴミを 食べ始める。　
好き嫌いはない。
最後は欠けた場所を埋めるように分泌液を出し➡
元の迷宮の姿へ復元する。
マルシル: 生物の治癒と同じ過程だよ。
魔物はさしずめ　
バイ菌を排除する免疫組織ってとこかも。

さしずめ seems to carry two major meanings, that being:
1.) something approximating 今のところ
2.) something approximating 結局, which I think is the usage here, but dictionaries seem a little inconsistent. The one that I found which made most sense was from 新明解:

㊀そのものの△特質（根本性格）を端的に表わせばそう言えると判断する様子。
「この遺跡は━現代のアミューズメント
センターといった所と思えばいいだろう」

Where I am curious is despite being defined as being similar to 結局, the nuance in this definition seems actually quite specific, so I wonder:
1.)How is this usage of this word used in practice? Is it generally interchangeable with 結局 or perhaps more formal (and/or more specific)?
2.)How is さしずめ applied in this dialogue? Like in the dialogue, is it usually in the form Nounはさしずめ/is this a usual usage of the word? I also notice that both the usage in the definition and the dialogue end in ところ, so I wonder if this is also a common form it appears in (Nounはさしずめ。。。といった/というところ)

As a starter, you can think of さしずめ as a slightly fancier alternative to いわば. Both are very commonly paired with expressions like ～のようなものだ, ～ということになる or ～といったところだ, and are used to explain the essence of a concept using a metaphor or such. The following two sentences are almost identical:

魔物は、いわば免疫組織といったところだ。
魔物は、さしずめ免疫組織といったところだ。

However, the nuance of 結局 ("after all; at the end of the day") is not completely lost, so this type of さしずめ tends to appear towards the end of an explanation, as in your example, whereas いわば can be used at the beginning of an explanation. Nevertheless, in terms of usage, さしずめ is much closer to いわば than to 結局.
I think this (as an alternative to いわば) is by far the most common use of さしずめ in contemporary Japanese. But there are several other minor uses:

"if I were to guess; likely; chances are" (as in 彼はさしずめ徹夜で勉強中だろう)
(nearly obsolete) "after all; at the end of the day"
(nearly obsolete) "for the time being; for now" (さしあたり, 当面 and 今の所 are much more common)


I am finding some discussions where people say that where さしずめ differs is by suggesting consideration to the metaphor/concept, where as いわば can be used as an adverb for any 言い換え. I think this is what you mean when you mention that 結局's meaning remains, but it seems to not just have to do with place in sentence but also hints to some result reached after consideration (I doubt that this is actually needed, but it seems to give a "well... let's just go with this" feel, which いわば seems to not inherently include).

@whatyouexpect Hmm... now that you mention it, さしずめ does tend to be used with a witty and/or unique metaphor. For example, "CPUはさしずめコンピュータの頭脳だ"  sounds a little awkward to me because this is a common and straightforward comparison used millions of times. This fact might have something to do with the nuance of "after consideration" in the dictionary. However, in practice, such a nuance is very subtle, and it's usually safe to consider it a synonym for いわば, but with a tendency to be used with witty metaphorical expressions. By the way, 明鏡国語辞典 explicitly lists いわば as a synonym for さしずめ.

Besides 差し当たり, 当面 and 今の所, what about とりあえず?

@weeab00 とりあえず is usually not a good replacement because it sounds relatively informal.

I would say 新明解's definition reflects the current usage by average speakers better. I think the current usage is even more specific. I've never recognized it as a synonym of 結局. It's closer to 例えるなら. You use it to explain the gist of something by making an analogy between it and another thing that is easier to understand or more representative of whatever you want to explain. It's indeed often paired with といったところ or the like.
I found an interesting blog article by 壇蜜, of all people.
For the first definition, 差し当たり is much more common.
